# How do I target test html elements in a Jest (/JQuery) test?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, jestjs

Jest novice here. I'm working through the DOM-manipulation Jest doc [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery), ultimately to test a JQuery change trigger in our Rails app, but failing at an early hurdle when trying to get JQuery to recognise the specific elements in my test html. So I have a `PledgeFormUpdates.test.js` file that simulates part of a form, my first ever non-toy Jest test, which looks like this:

```
'use strict';

import pledge_form_updates from '../../app/javascript/components/PledgeFormUpdates.js';

test('Displays GDPR checkbox on EU country selection', () => {

  pledge_form_updates();

  // Set up our document body
  document.body.innerHTML =
    '<select id="pledge_pledgor_home_country" class="country-select">' +
    '  <option value="Brazil" selected>Brazil</option>' +
    '  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>' +
    '</select>' +

    '<div id="js-gdpr-input" class="hidden">' +
    '  <div class="form-group">' +
    '    <div class="field-group" data-children-count="1">' +
    '      <input name="pledge[receive_comms]" disabled="disabled" type="hidden" value="0">' +
    '      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="pledge[receive_comms]" id="pledge_receive_comms">' +
    '      <label for="pledge_receive_comms" class="standard-label -checkbox">' +
    "        I'd like to be kept in the loop via the Founders Pledge email digest." +
    '      </label>' +
    '    </div>' +
    '  </div>' +
    '</div>'

  const $ = require('jquery');
  var country_select = $('#pledge_pledgor_home_country')
  console.log(country_select[0])
});
```

At the moment I don't have any expectations in there (and I won't waste space describing the JS file it's testing unless anyone requests it, since at the moment I'm getting unexpected behaviour even before I get that far). I would expect the last line to print something like this:

```
<select id="pledge_pledgor_home_country">
  <option value="Brazil" selected="">Brazil</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
</select>
```

(... or just `undefined` if it was finding nothing at all - which I confirmed by setting `country_select` to `$('#wibble')`)

But instead I'm getting something I don't understand:

```
HTMLSelectElement {}
```

What is this object, and more importantly, how do I access the element(s) I'm actually targeting?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the question as posed; though I suspect the answer will shortly lead to another question on here.

The container holding `HTMLSelectElement {}`, which I'd initially overlooked, seems to have access to the attributes (and perhaps other data?) of the element it's referring to.

So for example, `console.log(country_select);` prints `jQuery { '0': HTMLSelectElement {}, length: 1 }`, and if I target *that* element with standard JQuery interrogation methods, I get back approximately what I was expecting:

```
console.log(country_select.attr('class');
```

Prints `country-select`